# How to match Inkscape color to PowerPoint?

Tags: inkscape, color, microsoft-powerpoint, presentation-design

I am trying to create a slideshow with PowerPoint 365 (using Windows 10) and I was thinking on using some illustrations from Inkscape 1.1. For this I am trying to get the same color down in both programs.

The way I imagined it would work is for example I create an object in PowerPoint, and I inspect the RGB color value assigned to given object. Then I can take that RGB value and, by hand, set the Inkscape object's color to be the same exact value.

If I do this, and export my Inkscape graphics as png to be imported into PowerPoint, the colors don't match up.

For example the following two lines both have an RGB value of 229,20,10:

[image]

The color is obviously way off. I've tried reading a bit into it, and it seems like a different RGB definition is used somehow...? I don't fully understand the cause of the difference, however.

Could someone please explain me what's the normal way of making sure the RGB codes between two codes match up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Inkscape, go to *File > Document Properties*, and click on the *Colour* tab. From the *Available Colour Profiles* dropdown, choose the sRGB colour profile. Then export the PNG. This will ensure the image is saved with the correct colour profile.  This colour profile is the one used for colour reproduction on the web, and most software can recognise it.

[image]

Now you can insert the PNG into your PowerPoint document. I don't use PowerPoint, but a similar program called LibreOffice Impress. Here's a screenshot showing the correct colour of a graphic I made in Inkscape, then imported into Impress, using an on-screen colour picker. As you can see, the colour is 229,20,10 (#E5140A).

[image]Click on this image to enlarge

Comment: That's kind of interesting... to my knowledge, Inkscape does not use color profiles for PNG export. 

Those profiles there are only used for the 'CMS' color selector, and they are written into the SVG, too, so Scribus can make use of them.

sRGB is the standard for SVG, so ... it shouldn't even change anything.